# how can I use e.pageY in jQuery to perform an event when mouse is moving up and not down?

Tags: jquery

ok I am trying to create an event in jQuery that detects when a mouse is moving up. I am using
e.pageY event. so in this case I want the event to occur when the mouse's Y position is at less than 2. I have succesfully done that. here is the code.

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){ 

    if (e.pageY <= 2){

       $('#mystuff').show();

    });

 });
```

Now the problem is when I open the page and move the mouse down, the #mystuff shows since the mouse goes through a position less than 2.

I only want the #mystuff to show when the mouse is moving up and not moving down.

I hope you get the point.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
var mouseLastYPos = null;
$(document).mousemove(function(e){ 
    if(mouseLastYPos){ 
        if (e.pageY < mouseLastYPos && e.pageY <= 2){

           $('#mystuff').show();

        }
    }
    mouseLastYPos = e.pageY;
});​
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/bmHbt/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){ 
    var prevY = $('#mystuff').attr('data-prevY') || 0;
    if (e.pageY <= prevY){
       $('#mystuff').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#mystuff').hide();
    }
    $('#mystuff').attr('data-prevY', e.pageY);
 });
```

Check [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wMxLn/) with working example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a built-in way to detect which way the mouse is moving but you could do a workaround with a hidden field value that store the mouse position and compare the previous position, something like this:

```
if ($('#hiddenMousePos').val() > e.pageY){
    //Your code here
}
$('#hiddenMousePos').val(e.pageY);
```

and set the default value of `hiddenMousePos` to 0. That way it will only enter the condition if the previous e.pageY if bigger than the actual one.